# Complex type with single array element throws marshalling exception

Tags: web-services, wsdl, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, jax-rpc

We have JAX-RPC style web service, with a complex type defined as follows:

```
<xs:complexType name = "SomeFault">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name = "errorMessages" type="some:ErrorMessageWSType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:simpleType name = "ErrorMessageWSType">
<xs:restriction base = "xs:NMTOKEN">
<xs:enumeration value = "INVALID_1"/>
<xs:enumeration value = "INVALID_2"/>
<xs:enumeration value = "INVALID_3"/>
</xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

We are running into Marshaling exception on the server side when the response/fault complex type has a single array type field.

> weblogic.wsee.codec.CodecException: Failed to encode 
>   com.bea.xml.XmlException: failed to find a suitable binding type for
>   use in marshalling object
>   "[Lnamespace.type.ErrorMessageWSType;@693767e9". using schema type:
>   t=SomeFault@http://namespace/SOME/v1 java
>   type:namespace.type.ErrorMessageWSType[]

If we change SomeFault, by adding another element to the complex type the error goes away.

```
<xs:complexType name = "SomeFault">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name = "errorMessages" type="some:ErrorMessageWSType" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
<xs:element name = "dummyString" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Are we doing something wrong during the wsdlc code generation or is this a known issue?

A similar question is already posted at https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=4462906, but without any response, any pointers would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this solves the "why" part of the question, but you could try rewriting the sequence part like:

```
<xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:element name="errorMessages" type="some:ErrorMessageWSType"/>
</xs:sequence>
```

OTOH, what might be the mechanism that lets the second case work, but not the first? 
Might it be that the marshaller then has to figure out what `xsd:string` means before checking what `some:ErrorMessageWSType` means, and then has to wake up a resolver or something? 
This line of thought leads to the second approach I would try, which would be to declare `ErrorMessageWSType` *before* `SomeFault` (and perhaps in another namespace, just to see if that fixes anything).

Just my (tired) two cents, and I guess that both of these approaches presume a bug of some sort in the marshaller, because I can't really see that anything in your example code isn't according to the XML schema definition.

Comment: Tried both the approaches, got the same exception. anyways, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried another restriction base? From the XML schema definition (http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#NMTOKEN): "For compatibility (see Terminology (§1.4)) NMTOKEN should be used only on attributes." Try string instead, see what happens.

Comment: tried that option as well...no luck...got the same exception!